# error formating my secondary hdd

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, encryption, format

Ok so i am tring to format my secondary HDD and encrypt it... I have tried twice now and keep getting this error.. Please let me know if anymore information is needed and I will provide it.

[image: error]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you may be missing the `cryptsetup` utility.

Run `sudo apt install cryptsetup` and try it again.